# CSS Border declare 4 sides, color, width, in one line

Tags: css

I have this rule here:

```
border: 3px 0 0 0 solid #ccc;
```

Yet, it appears that the 4 sides are of the border are not registering.

```
border: 3px solid #ccc;
```

seems to work fine however.

Is there a way to make a one-liner with 4 side widths assigned?

Answer (score 24):

Though, there is no exact shorthand for the border, you can still put the width of the border in the same line;

```
border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
border-color: red;
border-style: solid;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

If I'm not mistaken, this is the closest you can get to *one line*:

```
border: solid #000;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`border`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#propdef-border) shorthand always sets equal width border on all sides; your first declaration is invalid.

You can use a one-liner, though:

```
border: 0 solid #ccc; border-top-width: 3px;
```

Comment: Doesn't look one-liner to me.

Comment: The answer implicitly states that you can't accomplish what the OP is trying to accomplish with one line. In order to do what the OP is trying to do, you HAVE to have more than one line.

Comment: @MatthewWolman The answer actually explicitly states "You can use a one-liner, though:"

Comment: @jmona789 You're interpreting the statement "one-liner" as literally meaning keeping all the text on one line. That is not the meaning of the statement "one-liner" when speaking to the context of CSS. A CSS one-liner is one declaration. You have two declarations in one line of text.

Comment: ”One-liner” is not a CSS term at all. If you think it means something else than the obvious meaning (text on one line), you should cite a definition supporting your idea.

Comment: @MatthewWolman I'm not interpreting the statement "one-liner" to mean anything.  I'm just saying you are incorrect when you said "The answer implicitly states that you can't accomplish what the OP is trying to accomplish with one line".  It clearly does not implicitly state that, because it explicitly states it can use a one-liner.  Whether or not it's truly a one-liner doesn't change the text in the answer.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: Because you asked: A CSS "one-liner" consists of single property and its value(s).

Because it's true: There is no one-liner to create a border that's different on each side.