# How to color all 4 sides of a TD cell border via CSS in an HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I have this code where I am trying to color all 4 sides of a TD cell with red, but if you run the code, only the bottom and the right border are getting color (in Mozilla Firefox).  Is there a way to color all 4 borders?

```css
#selections_table table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#selections_table td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="selections_table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Model</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td style="border-color:red">XXX-8</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This question/answer does not help: [CSS Border declare 4 sides, color, width, in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464228/css-border-declare-4-sides-color-width-in-one-line)

If there is a way to style it via a class, that will be better than using a an inline style command.

Comment: Did any of these solutions work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your inline style to `style="border:1px double red;"`:

```
<div id="selections_table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Model</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td style="border:1px double red;">XXX-8</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A little trick, create an `::after` to the td you want to add the border.

```css
#selections_table table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

#selections_table td,
 th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
  position:relative;
}
#selections_table td.border-red::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="selections_table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Model</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="border-red">XXX-8</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ym82a0k7/

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="selections_table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Model</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>XXX-8</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to declare `td` here:

```
#selections_table td,th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
}
```

So,

```
#selections_table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This is another option (by increasing the pixel, it is not a good practice but another option)

```
#selections_table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
}

td {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

or just like this:

```
#selections_table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
}

td {
    border: 1px double red;
}
```